# Exception whith fragment animation

Tags: android, android-fragments, illegalstateexception

I have two fragments in app. Code which switches them:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{

    Fragment1 fragment1;
    Fragment2 fragment2;


    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.some_layout);

        fragment1 = new Fragment1();
        fragment2 = new Fragment2();

        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fragment_vert_add, R.anim.fragment_vert_remove);
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.linear_layout_id, fragment1);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    public void changeFragment() {

        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fragment_vert_add, R.anim.fragment_vert_remove);

        if(fragment1.isAdded())
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.linear_layout_id, fragment2);
        else
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.linear_layout_id, fragment1);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

}
```

when I touch the screen during the animation:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No activity 
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1123)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1118)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1927)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1800)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:977)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1136)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1499)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:456)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you show activity code?

Comment: And maybe post the whole stack trace.

Comment: Try running the animation on the UI thread and see if that stops the crash. Im not entirely sure what "swithes them" means but an IllegalStateException is being thrown because your trying to operate on the fragment when it is not in the appropriate state. Check this out ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15784155/java-lang-illegalstateexception-no-activity)

Comment: When is `changeFragment()` called?

Comment: changeFragment() called from this fragments for replace it

Comment: i have the same problem any luck fixing this?